# Ionic - loader while pressing button

Tags: typescript, button, ionic-framework, loader

Good day,

I currently have the requirement of, while pressing a button, that a loader should appear... the reason behind this is to avoid accidental pressing of a button, and showing the progress of the longpress...

I was able to get the start and end of the press, and the time between the two presses, however I am struggling to get a custom loader to start for the time of the press. This is a fairly new framework for our company and myself and I am still learning...

The loader we setup was installed from https://github.com/bootsoon/ng-circle-progress...

Here is my touch events code (.ts file):

```
touchEvent(e)
{
  console.log(e);
  if(e.type == 'mousedown' || e.type == 'touchstart')
  {
    this.sTime = new Date();
    console.log(this.sTime.valueOf());
    this.startLoader(); //this is currently not working
  }

  if(e.type == 'mouseup' || e.type == 'touchend')
  {
    this.eTime = new Date();
    console.log(this.eTime.valueOf());

    var diff = this.eTime.valueOf() - this.sTime.valueOf();
    var diffText = diff + 'ms';
    this.time.innerHTML = diffText;
    this.stopLoader(); // this currently is not working
  }
  console.log(e.timeStamp);
}
```

The progress definition in the html file (in ion-content):

```
<ion-row>
  <ion-col col-12 #progressTesting>
    <circle-progress
      class="center"
      [percent]="100"
      [animation]="true"
      [animationDuration]="3000"
      id='progressTest' 
    ></circle-progress>
  </ion-col>
</ion-row>
```

I also did the import on the module.ts file to use the progress indicator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using an observable to get this to work...

```
startLoader(eType) { //eType is the event type
  this.showloader = true; // this is a public variable which i use in HTML side in a *ngIf to show or hide the loader

  this.myObservable =  Observable.create(observer => {
   observer.next(
        this.dealWithNextObserver(observer,eType)
    );

    setInterval(() => {
      observer.next(
        this.dealWithNextObserver(observer,eType)
      );
    },30);
  });

  this.myObservable.subscribe((data) => {
  console.log('observer did run');

  });
}

dealWithNextObserver(observer,type)
{
  if(type !== 'mousedown' && type !== 'touchstart')
  {
    this.showloader = false;
    observer.complete();
  }
}
```

I also updated my touchEvent Method:

```
touchEvent(e)
{
  console.log(e);

  if(e.type == 'mousedown' || e.type == 'touchstart')
  {
    this.sTime = new Date();
    console.log(this.sTime.valueOf());
    this.startLoader(e.type);
  }

  if(e.type == 'mouseup' || e.type == 'touchend')
  {
    this.eTime = new Date();
    console.log(this.eTime.valueOf());
  }
  console.log(e.timeStamp);
}
```